How can I trigger Hangfire recurring jobs using Jalali dates?
I'm trying to set up recurring jobs in Hangfire that use the Jalali (Shamsi) calendar. Specifically, I want to trigger jobs based on events like "the last day of the Shamsi month" or "the first day of the Shamsi week."
I've attempted changing the culture settings of my project, but I didn't achieve the expected results. I also want to avoid converting dates to Jalali manually.
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa-IR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
  
      
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Remove(
                 GlobalJobFilters.Filters.OfType<JobFilter>().Where(c => c.Instance is CaptureCultureAttribute).FirstOrDefault().Instance
            );

Is there any way to support Jalali dates in Hangfire for job scheduling?
Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Hangfire's recurring jobs typically use the Cron expressions based on the Gregorian calendar, which may not directly support the Jalali (Persian) calendar.
You can always use the native System.Globalization.PersianCalendar. You can convert GregorianDate date to Persian Date and can check for specific days.
using Hangfire;
using System.Globalization;
using System;

public class JalaliScheduler
{
    public static void ScheduleDailyJalaliJob(string jobId, Action jobAction)
    {
        // Trigger the job daily
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobId, () => ExecuteJalaliJob(jobAction), Cron.Daily);
    }

    private static void ExecuteJalaliJob(Action jobAction)
    {
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();

        int jalaliYear = persianCalendar.GetYear(currentDate);
        int jalaliMonth = persianCalendar.GetMonth(currentDate);
        int jalaliDay = persianCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(currentDate);

        // Example: Only run the job on a specific Jalali date (e.g., 1st Farvardin)
        if (jalaliMonth == 1 && jalaliDay == 1) // 1st Farvardin (Jalali New Year)
        {
            jobAction.Invoke();
        }
    }
}


JalaliScheduler.ScheduleDailyJalaliJob("jalali-job", () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Jalali specific job executed!");
});


Hope this will help.

It's actually what ChatGPT suggested me to do:
Set a recurring job to run daily. This job will check if today is the last day of the Persian month, and if so, it will execute your desired logic.
But I don't want to do it; I want to see my hangfire dashboard clear
